# Entity Framework Core 2 HasDefaultValueSql() not working with MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

**So, I have a Model with a prop like this:**

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

**Im trying to set a default value to this field like this:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().Property(r => r.Date).HasDefaultValueSql("NOW()");
```

The problem is that the database column default value isnt set. When I use the "NOW()" function, the migration works but as I said, the column default isnt set in the database. And when I try other MySql datetime functions I get this error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1*

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've done something very similar in my project with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and it works. See [here](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/a5a1ee93a34bf85aa4685abadc6bb3309c10a6bb/src/FilterLists.Data/EntityTypeConfigurations/SnapshotTypeConfiguration.cs). Can you post the relevant code in your migration file? Also, which EF provider are you using for MySQL? I've had the best luck with Pomelo's.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that your property name is `Date` but the property in your modelBuilder statement is `Data`. That might be the issue.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett Im using Pomelo's provider. Oh and the Data/Date was just a mispell that I did only here.

Heres the migration code:

`b.Property<DateTime>("Date")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");`

Comment: This migration code that I pasted, was when I tried to use "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()" instead of "NOW()".

Comment: so, someone has a solution? i tried current_timestamp() and now() but without succeed :(

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same problem, while I made the migration files by `.Net` itself as described in [this tutorial](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database).

```
entity.Property(e => e.ValidFrom)
                    .HasColumnName("valid_from")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("'current_timestamp()'"); //<-- Line of problem!
```

I didn't expected for any error in an auto generated code! *However, it was a bug not my fault or .Net bug.*

The problem actually came from a bug in [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) library. I discussed it with the developers [here](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/171#issuecomment-657255200).

As I he said:

> So you have to remove the single quotes ...

I removed the single quotes and the problem [resolved](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/171#issuecomment-657258642).

At the end the solution was:

```
entity.Property(e => e.ValidFrom)
                    .HasColumnName("valid_from")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime")
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("current_timestamp()");
```

Anyway, they said they will solve it for MariaDB also very soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use "getdate()" instead of "NOW()